# How to make a wheel teeter to a certain angle?

Tags: java, math

I need to make a wheel fall on 1 of five angles and I want it to teeter when it gets to the angle. After the user spins the wheel, I have it slow down by multiplying the rotation velocity by .98 per tick. I sort of have it working by finding the closest of the angles and adding a small value in its direction to the velocity. However this looks unrealistic and can be glitchy.

I was thinking of implementing a damped sine wave but i'm not sure how I would do this.

Current Pseudocode:

```
var rotation, rotationVelocity, stoppingPoints[5];
update(deltaT) {
    velocity -= rotationVelocity * 0.5 * dt;
    closestAngle = findClosestAngle().angle;
    rotationVelocity += (closestAngle - rotation) / 36 * dt;
    rotation += rotationVelocity; 
}
```

Edit:

Teeter: move or balance unsteadily; sway back and forth:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subtract a constant amount from it's velocity every iteration until it reaches zero

not only does this actually represent how friction works in real life, but it's easier too.

If you want it to move as though it were connected to a spring:

Hooke's law for springs is `F = -kx` where `k` is a constant and x is the distance from the origin if you want it to sway back and forth as though it were on a spring.  keep track of it's rotation from an origin, and add `-kx` where `x` is it's rotational distance(or angle) from the origin.

Now, if you apply both friction and hooke's law to the spring, it should look realistic.

Comment: thats not my problem. i'm trying to figure out how to make it teeter

Comment: @stas what do you mean teeter, do you mean come back as it reaches the end?

Comment: i added the definition. by the way your suggestion for friction actually works much better than what I had before even though thats not my question :)

Comment: dude i owe u my life :). I asked my physics teacher and he told me to use use the limit of a damped harmonic function and i was like 0.0

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest angle that you want is the cloest to where it will stop. You can simulate where it will end, how long it takes to end, and use that to determine how much extra(or less) velocity you'll need.

Not sure what you mean by teetering exactly.

Comment: Teeter: move or balance unsteadily; sway back and forth.

Comment: Sure but, your problem extends the raw definition on teeter. When do you want to teeter?

Comment: I think he means like in wheel of fortune, where the wheel doesn't just stop on a dime.

Comment: If it passes the point, it will accelerate back towards it and it might pass it again to a certain degree.

Comment: When the wheel stops give it the amount of velocity such that it will go 1.5 times the distance of the starting point. When it stop again it will recalculate and eventually stop where you want

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to model a wheel with weights attached at the `stoppingPoints`. I mean, from a physics viewpoint. There is the existing rotational velocity, then deceleration from friction, and an unknown acceleration/deceleration caused by the effects of gravity on those points (as translated to a rotational velocity based on the position of the weights). Anyway, that's my interpretation and would probably be my approach (to model the gravity).

I think the teetering you speak of will be achieved when the acceleration caused by the weights exceeds the existing rotational velocity.